# Blender Crashing regularly

Tags: interface

Whenever I do not press a key on blender 2.82a for 10-20 seconds and then go to do something, it keeps crashing like this;

[image: BLENDER FILE CRASHING]

Am i doing something wrong or am i likely to have something turned on/off which i shouldn't?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your crash log?
https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/troubleshooting/crash.html#crash-log

Comment: Where would i find that? It isn't actually crashing, as i can scroll over the affected areas and they will return to normal, so its kind of like a temporary crash, ive never experienced it before in 3/4 years of using blender until i downloaded 2.82a

Comment: It seems an hardware problem. With updated drivers, I would do a stress test to check if the hardware is working as expected. If everything is fine, you can try to reinstall blender in a new folder and Load Factory settings (then remember to reactivate GPU if available).

Comment: also for these type of errors please always include what OS you are running and what Graphicscard you have

Comment: I have an nvidia 1070 gtx and i am currently using windows 10